# I can't search using urllib with speech_recognition (im a beginner)

Tags: python, speech-recognition, urllib

I'm trying to search a string in a website but just can't..

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import urllib
import urllib.request
import re

page = urllib.request.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page").read()

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("say something: ")
    audio = r.listen(source)

flag = False
try:

    print("you said: " + r.recognize_google(audio,))

    flag = True

except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("error")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("error; {0}".format(e))


if flag:
    re.findall(r.recognize_google(audio), page)
    page.find(r.recognize_google(audio))

else:
    print("error")
```

**error is**

return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Comment: The web page is a string encoded as bytes. You need to decode the string, probably using the utf-8 codec. You can see an example in the question I linked. Once both your webpage and search pattern are a string, you can search it.

Comment: what is `speech_recognition` supposed to do here?

Comment: @NickODell i dont know which one to decode

Comment: @AşkınCihan The variable `page` is of type bytes. Decode that one.

Comment: @leiyang just trying using modules that i've learned.